# One Month Rails - Going Online With Heroku - Application Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have reached the "Going Online With Heroku" section of One Month Rails. 
After following the steps

```
` Pudge@PUDGE-PC ~/desktop/pinteresting (master)
  $ heroku keys:add
  Found the following SSH public keys:
  1) github_rsa.pub
  2) id_rsa.pub
  Which would you like to use with your Heroku account? 2
  Uploading SSH public key C:/Users/Pudge/.ssh/id_rsa.pub... done
  Pudge@PUDGE-PC ~/desktop/pinteresting (master)
  $ heroku create
  Creating evening-oasis-5199... done, stack is cedar
  http://evening-oasis-5199.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:evening-oasis-5199.git

  Git remote heroku added`
```

I open the app at the given location and it comes back with "Application Error"

```
`←[36m2014-03-11T00:16:24.525751+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Enable Logplex by chitrad
 er84@gmail.com
 ←[36m2014-03-11T00:16:24.525824+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Release v2 created by chi
 trader84@gmail.com
 ←[33m2014-03-11T00:16:38.664429+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H14 desc
 ="No web processes running" method=GET path=/ host=evening-oasis-5199.herokuapp.
 com request_id=8229c76f-de74-43d6-ac14-fa3ecefe8ff6 fwd="99.9.45.163" dyno= conn
 ect= service= status=503 bytes=
 ←[33m2014-03-11T00:26:09.486092+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H14 desc
 ="No web processes running" method=GET path=/ host=evening-oasis-5199.herokuapp.
 com request_id=afba73c5-ad0d-41a2-8d0c-9faf75dc4e0b fwd="99.9.45.163" dyno= conn
 ect= service= status=503 bytes=
 ←[33m2014-03-11T00:26:09.717414+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H14 desc
 ="No web processes running" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=evening-oasis-5199
 .herokuapp.com request_id=4c3f6b80-1f0a-42d5-80f6-3510b093872b fwd="99.9.45.163"
  dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
  ←[33m2014-03-11T00:28:09.983774+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H14 desc
  ="No web processes running" method=GET path=/ host=evening-oasis-5199.herokuapp.
  com request_id=21b356bb-cbcb-4489-82e5-6e6d0c69dfd5 fwd="99.9.45.163" dyno= conn
  ect= service= status=503 bytes=
  ←[33m2014-03-11T00:28:10.239213+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H14 desc
  ="No web processes running" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=evening-oasis-5199
  .herokuapp.com request_id=fcf0e24d-f9f6-42a5-b382-841ed9704e1e fwd="99.9.45.163"
   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
   ←[32m2014-03-11T03:15:10+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]:←[0m Slug compilation start
   ed
   ←[32m2014-03-11T03:15:32+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]:←[0m Slug compilation faile
   d: failed to compile Ruby app
   ←[36m2014-03-11T03:15:57.572557+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Starting process with com
   mand `rake db:migrate` by chitrader84@gmail.com
   ←[35m2014-03-11T03:15:59.264402+00:00 heroku[run.1396]:←[0m Starting process wit
  h command `rake db:migrate`
  ←[35m2014-03-11T03:15:59.226632+00:00 heroku[run.1396]:←[0m Awaiting client
  ←[35m2014-03-11T03:15:59.359699+00:00 heroku[run.1396]:←[0m State changed from s
  tarting to up
  ←[35m2014-03-11T03:16:01.043376+00:00 heroku[run.1396]:←[0m State changed from u
  p to complete
  ←[35m2014-03-11T03:16:01.037656+00:00 heroku[run.1396]:←[0m Process exited with
   status 1
  ←[33m2014-03-11T03:16:10.744992+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H14 desc
  ="No web processes running" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=evening-oasis-5199
  .herokuapp.com request_id=add463f3-a0ad-4682-aa06-b0e7649481a3 fwd="99.9.45.163"
   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Here is what my log says.

Comment: check the heroku logs to see what the error may be, have you created a database and run migration?

Comment: @jamesy829 It doesn't speak of creating a database or running migration so i'm just going to say no.

Comment: However, the logs say something like ="No web processes running" thats about the only thing that looks wrong from my point of view

Comment: Have you done your initial push of code?  I see you have done heroku create but have you done git push heroku master?

Comment: from my understanding, because heroku uses thin server by default, you should be creating a Procfile that defines how to run, sample Procfile `web: bundle exec thin start -p $PORT`

Comment: this is all guesswork. can you post your code somewhere so we can see what you are up to? i guess it's just example code anyways.

Comment: where can I post the code. That would help a lot. I have done my initial push. Everything has worked fine thus far in the tutorial. Can't seem to figure this one out though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just did a quick creation to test.

I did
step1:

```
rails new testapp
cd testapp
git add .
git commit -m 'initial commit'
heroku create
```

at this point, i did

```
heroku open
```

and I get the same application error with the same "No web processes running"

My feeling is you stopped here and not pushed your initial commit

You would need to run this additionally:

```
git push heroku master
heroku run rake db:migrate          <--- only needed if you have migrations
heroku open
```

Comment: Followed the latter steps with pushing. I have done an initial push btw. I could also link whatever you need.

Comment: run a tail on the logfile:  heroku logs --tail         then paste in here your results after running heroku open

Comment: Is there a way to post it all. It's quite a bit of log. It won't fit in the comment. Sorry noob <---

Comment: just post some near the end. you can edit your original question and put it there.  We just need more info to help you properly

Comment: Based on your log, your app isnt pushed up to heroku.  There was  probably an error on push.  A common error is to check your gemfile and make sure you dont have a sqlite gem in there.  If you do, then heroku will reject your push.  Try to comment it out, bundle install, git add .  then git commit then git push heroku master again

Comment: Wow it worked. So what do I do with the sqlite3 gem I commented out. Even though the tutorial shows it in their. Just leave it at the moment?

Comment: You would use the pg gem on heroku .  Heroku doesnt support sqlite but has support for pg.  Check out https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4

Answer (score 0):

The error log says "No web processes running".

So how about running one?

Try this

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

Comment: That worked for me. Now trying to investigate if I have a problem with my Procfile. I'm trying to get multiple buildpacks (Ruby and Python) to work side-by-side.